# Eclipse does not build *.class binary for a java library of final classes with static final fields

Tags: java, eclipse, build

Here's the gist:

```
package allProperties;

public final class SomeProperties
{
    /**
     * Custom JSON property names.
     */
    public static final String property1 = "StringConstant1";
    public static final String property2 = "StringConstant2";
    ....
}
```

With only this type of code in a project, there's no .class generated in the bin directory, so I cannot build a .jar from a project that references this project.

I tried turning off automatic building to manually build the project with no luck.

The binary can be forced to generate by temporarily adding a main() method to that class itself - adding a Program.java with an entry point in the project won't do it either. But that hardly seems a proper solution.

Will any Eclipse/Java experts grace me with your helping hand?

Comment: If you are using JavaProject , Class file will be available in bin\allProperties.

Comment: Thanks @Thillakan, but my problem is that it isn't there. Without a main() method in that class no class file gets generated even if I manually trigger build.